# Is there an elseif thing in MongoDB to $cond while aggregating

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I need a custom field calculated in MongoDB as follows

```
if( field1 =="A")  ->customfield=10
else if(field1 =="B"  )->customfield=20
else (field1 =="C" ) ->customfield=15
```

I'm using aggregation along with the $project statement. But the $cond operator doesn't allow elseif (subbranching the else) and merely allows two static branches if and else. Using a nested elseif causes

`"exception: field inclusion is not allowed inside of $expressions"`

Heres my query(which gives me the error)

```
db.items.aggregate([ { $project :
{
     name: 1,
     customfield:
     {
         $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$field1", "4" ] }, then: 30,
                else: {
                    if: 
                    { $eq: ["$field1","8"]}, 
                    then: 25, else: 10}}
               }
           }},{ $sort: { customfield: 1 }},{$limit:12}]);
```

Is there a method or workaround to this. My apologies if this is a repeated question but I wasn't able to find a similar one.

Comment: You have "$field1" and then "field1". Typo?

Comment: Thanks but that was a result of my hurry(in typing it out). Edited the same to reflect the original query ,apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think there is any syntax that can shorten your query. You'll have to nest the `if` inside the `else`.

Comment: @ nvm guys I found the solution.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 79, accepted):

With modern releases ( since MongoDB 3.4 ) you would use [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/), which is basically the counterpart to `switch` or `case` keywords in other language implementations:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "customfield": {
      "$switch": {
        "branches": [
          { "case": { "$eq": [ "$field1", "4" ] }, "then": 30 },
          { "case": { "$eq": [ "$field1", "8" ] }, "then": 25 }
        ],
        "default": 10
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { customfield: 1 }},
  { "$limit":12 }
])
```

This avoids *nesting* the `if..then..else` conditions as can be done using [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and shown below. But the below still shows as an example that this could always be done, even before the new operator of even the explicit `if..then..else` keywords since the original array notation always maintained that syntax.

Noting also that an *array* of conditions here is typically also a lot easier to construct programatically than creating a *nested* data structure for the statement as was needed with [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).

---

The `if..then..else` keywords to the [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator are only a recent addition as of recent versions of MongoDB at the time of writing ( MongoDB 2.6 was the introduction of the *keywords*. The actual operator was available with release of the aggregation framework in MongoDB 2.2 ). The intention was for clarity but in this case it seems to has caused some confusion.

As an `if..then.else` operator [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is indeed a [**ternary**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) operator, just as would be implemented in many programming languages. This means as an "inline" conditional, rather than creating "blocks" of logic to the conditions, anything that does not meet the first condition belongs under `else`.

Therefore you "nest" the statements rather than follow blocks:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "customfield": {
      "$cond": { 
        "if": { "$eq": [ "$field1", "4" ] }, 
        "then": 30,
        "else": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": ["$field1","8"]}, 
            "then": 25, 
            "else": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { customfield: 1 }},
  { "$limit":12 }
]);
```

Or even with the original *array* notation, which some might prefer if building the statement programatically:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "customfield": {
      "$cond": [
         { "$eq": [ "$field1", "4" ] }, 
         30,
         { "$cond": [
           { "$eq": ["$field1","8"] },
           25, 
           10
         ]}
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { customfield: 1 }},
  { "$limit":12 }
]);
```

Ternary means three conditions, no more no less. So all `if..then..else` logic must be nested.

Comment: Oh I so wish ,U had typed a  bit earlier before I corrected it myself. Nonethelss would mark this as the answer,Thanks

Comment: @neil-lunn: You missed double quote after then keyword in else part

Comment: How to add or operater along with this?

Comment: Could you suggest how to filter out the default value? Since its integer here (and the same in my case), $filter doesnt really work

Answer (score 17):

MongoDB 3.4 has a new thing called `$switch` for this exact thing!

```
$switch: {
   branches: [
      { case: <expression>, then: <expression> },
      { case: <expression>, then: <expression> },
      ...
   ],
   default: <expression>
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/

Answer (score 2):

Here is way i prefer.

Syntax

```
$cond: [ { <condition> }, <true>, <false> ]
```

Example

```
condition1: {
    $cond: [ { $eq: ["one", 'one'] }, true, false ]
},

condition2: {
    $cond: [ { $eq: ["one", 'two'] }, true, false ]
},

condition3: {
    $cond: [ { $eq: ["three", 'three'] }, {three:'is equal to three'}, {three:'is not equal to three'} ]
}
```

output

```
{
 condition1: true,
 condition2: false,
 condition3: { three: 'is equal to three' },
}
```

Comment: This is the best way as of now!

Comment: nice, it working

Answer (score -1):

if you are using only object then

```
{
    $cond: {
        $and: [
            { if: { $eq: ["$$field1", 'A'] }, then: '10', else: 15 },
            { if: { $eq: ["$$field1", 'B'] }, then: '20', else: 15 },
            { if: { $eq: ["$$field1", 'C'] }, then: '10', else: 15 },
        ]
    }
}
```

And if you are Using Array find Data

```
{
    $map: {
        input: "$fields", as: "field1", in: {
            $cond: {
                $and: [
                    { if: { $eq: ["$$field1", 'A'] }, then: '10', else: 15 },
                    { if: { $eq: ["$$field1", 'B'] }, then: '20', else: 15 },
                    { if: { $eq: ["$$field1", 'C'] }, then: '10', else: 15 },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```