# MongoDB aggregation pipeline $addFields with $cond - not able to use variables

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am not able to use variables in the `$cond` in the pipeline stage. I want to add a field (`processedToday` inside `documentPropertiesProcessed`) but based on condition depending on the value of another variable `postProcessingOperatorValidationCount`.

The snippet of pipeline stage (as configured in python code) is as follows:

- add flag if the document was processed today

```
{
    "$addFields": {
        "documentPropertiesProcessed.processedToday": {
            "$cond": [
                {"$gte":
                 [
                     "$$documentPropertiesProcessed.postProcessingOperatorValidationCount",
                     5
                 ]
                },
                "no",
                "yes"]
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, the error message received is as follows:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Use of undefined variable: documentPropertiesProcessed, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1620930938, 1), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Use of undefined variable: documentPropertiesProcessed', 'code': 17276, 'codeName': 'Location17276', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1620930938, 1), 'signature': {'hash': b'_\x05f&\xb3\x16\xdd\x01\x00T\xe2\xa3\x04L\xa5\xd6r\x88X\x88', 'keyId': 6953591995419852803}}}

I went through the documents and questions but still not able to understand as to where the issue lies. The variables are very much present. Any pointers and guidelines will be very helpful.

Comment: Use single Dollar sign instead of 2. `"$documentPropertiesProcessed.postProcessingOperatorValidationCount"`

Comment: removed one $ and executed the pipeline. The error has gone away, but the field value is not set as per the results of the comparison. All values are set as "no". Now the $gte is not taking effect.

Comment: Please share sample source data, expected output, and your code snippet all of which are masked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are attempting to achieve an if-then-else block in conventional coding terms? If that is the case you will have to do the following ( please note that I havent checked for the syntax and this is just a sample

```
`"$cond": { 
        "if": { "$gt": [ "$$documentPropertiesProcessed.postProcessingOperatorValidationCount", "5" ] }, 
        "then": $date,
        "else": ''
          }`
```

check this link as well : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479347/is-there-an-elseif-thing-in-mongodb-to-cond-while-aggregating]